# Why does C# not allow calling base.SomeAbstractMethod

Tags: c#, oop, abstract-class

Here is some code for the discussion

```
  abstract class ClassA
  {
    public abstract void StartProcess();
  }

  class ClassB : ClassA
  {
    public override void StartProcess()
    {      
      Console.WriteLine("ClassB: Render");
    }
  }

  class ClassC : ClassA
  {
    public override void StartProcess()
    {
      base.StartProcess();//This is where the compiler complains
      Console.WriteLine("ClassC: Render");
    }
  }
```

Before everyone jumps down my throat, let me just say that I'm fully aware of the why it does not. But there are cases where being able to do so would make sense and prevent having to declare the base class's method as virtual but with an empty implementation.

Coming from Delphi background, we could do this in Delphi and used it in our class design. If you made the mistake of calling the abstract method on the base class (at run time) you've got an "Abstract Error".

Then I wished the (Delphi) complier check me before!
Now I wish the (C#) complier would let me do this!
How weird is that?

The Questions:
Could not the complier/Jitter simply ignore such a call and issue a warning instead of error?
Do others see/feel this pain?

The case I have, where I need this is the following:
ClassA is part of a library (no control over this class)
ClassC is generated (kind of like how an ASP.NET page gets compiled or a Razor View gets compiled.

But a user of the library can define a ClassB and then ClassC will descend from ClassB instead of ClassA (when it gets generated). Similar to how ASP.NET pages normally descend from System.Web.UI.Page but if you've defined your own "base" page and other pages in your app now descendant from your base page then the generated class descends from your base page (which is turn descends from System.Web.UI.Page).

I hope that part is clear. Then looking at the code I've presented, I can't get instances of ClassC to call into the implementation of ClassB because the code gen doesn't know to include base.StartProcess().

**EDIT**
It seem that some people didn't quite get what I've written. So let's say you were writing the code generation part that generates ClassC that descends from ClassA. Well, since the method is anstract (in ClassA) you can't generate the line of code that calls into StartProcess() (because the complier won't allow it). As a result, if anyone define a ClassB, the code generation still won't call base.StartProcess(). This is in fact what happens in ASP.NET MVC views.

Ideally I'd like the compiler to ignore it. It ignore many things like calling dispose on a null reference for example.

I'm trying to have a discussion rather be preached to...

**EDIT2**
Let's assume we have a hierarchy as shown in the code above and it worked.
The opportunity we have now is that the base class, ClassA could have an implementation (in the future) for StartProcess() descendants would call into it. The only way to do this today is to define the method virtual with no body. But that feels a bit icky to me.

Comment: "But there are cases where being able to do so would make sense" I'm waiting...

Comment: Not surprising - people here are always out to show how much smarter they are. I thought we could have a discussion rather than a pissing contest...too bad. I've editing my question to include some other info, if you care.

Comment: @Jackie: To my mind it still doesn't make sense. If your code generator is explicitly declaring ClassC to derive from ClassA, then I don't see how ClassB is going to get involved. I'm still very glad the C# compiler behaves the way it does. The code generator would need to know about ClassB to make ClassC derive from it, and it can check easily whether or not there's an implementation to call. No problem.

Comment: @Jackie: You might also want to look at Timwi's comment to my post - if you *want* a no-op implementation of StartProcess, you can provide one in ClassA. Again, no problem. So there are ways of doing whatever you want, as far as I can see, without removing the compile-time safety of prohibiting a call which *can't possibly* work.

Comment: @Jon, ClassA in not in my control. The Code generation (which is also not in my control) will make classC descend from ClassB is that's what it has been told (as explained in my question). I believe, that because the method is abstract in ClassA the code generation doesn't care to "look" and call (or not call) classB's StartProcess() method. However, if one could call abstract methods and have the compiler/jitter ignore it then the code generation could have a call to base.StartProcess() and all would be good.

Comment: @Jon, to continue... Granted in this case the code generation could be improved but this is just an example I'm providing. I know I've had to re-think this aspect by providing a virtual method with no code in the implementation in my base classes just I can do this kind of thing. That does feel icky to me. And it prevent any change in the future from "taking" as well. That is if all descendants called base.StartProcess(), you have the opportunity to have an implementation in the base class in the future. As it stands now, that's not an option without changing every descendant to call base.xxx

Comment: @Jackie: You've provided an example of a code generator being broken. Breaking the language isn't the right way to compensate for a broken code generator - the right change to make is to fix the code generator, or the base class. If the code generator got the case of a method call wrong, would that be an argument for C# to become case-insensitive? No. And if you want a no-op method if nothing overrides it, that's *exactly* what an empty virtual method is meant to do. An abstract method *forces* reimplementation, which isn't the same thing at all.

Comment: @Jon, it seems impossible to get through to you :). From your reply to my comment it seems as if you skipped the part where I say I'm using it as an example. Just to be clear, I *don't* have an outstanding problem per se. I don't need a solution or workaround for something I've got on my plate. I was hoping to have a discussion. Pros **and** cons. I'm fully aware of the reasons for why things are the way they are (I implied that in my question quite clearly I think). Oh well, let's just forget I asked.

Comment: @Jackie: If something doesn't solve a genuine problem but it *introduces* problems (and I count "deferring a coding error to execution time when it's currently spotted at compile time") as introducing a problem then I don't see that there's much need for discussion. You claim that you wish the C# compiler would act as the Delphi compiler did - if you don't have an outstanding problem, why are you wishing for that? If you're proposing a change, there should at least be a concrete *good* example of where it would be useful. I don't think "imagine a broken code generator" counts.

Answer (score 10):

How could it possibly make sense to call `base.StartProcess()` when that's been declared to be abstract? There can't possibly be an implementation to call, so the compiler prohibits it.

Personally I *like* seeing errors at compile-time instead of either seeing an error at execution time or making the JITter *ignore* a call which I've specifically made. What if it returned a value which you assigned to a variable? What should that variable value be if the method doesn't exist?

If ClassC is going to derive from ClassB, then you won't get the problem - because you won't be calling into an abstract base method. But your code *declares* that it derives directly from ClassA instead, not ClassB. If ClassC is generated, it should be generated to derive from ClassB instead, which would be fine.

Personally I think the compiler is doing exactly the right thing here.

EDIT: Just to make it *absolutely* clear what I believe the appropriate solutions are:

- If you want to be able to call `base.M()` from any derived class, you should make it a virtual method with a no-op implementation, instead of an abstract method.
- If you have a code generator which should generate a call to `base.M()` only in the situations where it's generating a class whose base class has an implementation of `M`, then it's up to the code generator to get that right - the language shouldn't make everyone else suffer (by deferring error reporting to execution time, or worse still swallowing that error by simply performing a no-op) just because one tool has been written incorrectly.

I think the downsides of *either* making it an execution-time error to call an abstract base method *or* making it a no-op are worse than the issues described in the question.

Now an interesting language feature which *could* potentially be useful here would be the idea of a virtual method which forced overrides to call the base implementation either before or after the override... in a similar way to how a constructor in a derived class always has to call a constructor in the base class either directly or via another constructor. I strongly suspect that the complexity of such a feature (what would happen to the return value? How would use specify before/after semantics? What about exceptions?) would outweigh the benefits. In simple class hierarchies, the [template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) can perform the same duty in a simpler way.

Comment: +1 for the idea that the compiler should not compile garbage. This is not Perl we're talking about here.

Comment: Good answer, but I was hoping to find something on the lines of: If you want the `base` method call to do nothing, then you shouldn’t be surprised that you need to declare a base method that *explicitly does nothing*. If all abstract methods were treated as if they were virtual methods with empty bodies, there would be no point in having the `abstract` marker on methods anymore.

Comment: @Jon, I like your "interesting language feature". I've wished for something like this too. Specifically, for a way base classes can somehow specify more explicitly (and probably control) how derived class are to behave. The Template Method Pattern doesn't offer this control. It allows a base class to determine a sequence of "steps" or method calls but in no way can enforce calls to base.Foo(). So going back to the other point, would love to have a discussion on that. Sure there will be a lot of things to be worked out but that's the point!

Comment: @Jon: I also think that this feature would be too complex to be worth it. As an alternative, take a look at _traits_. They're generally a better construct to design reusable code. In [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/126), for example, there's the concept of a [self-type](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/124), which is the type that the trait _requires_ to be present when a class chooses to compose it. _Unlike_ with a base type, the trait can call abstract methods on that self-type. Since traits are composed, not inherited, they're just virtual method calls.

Comment: @Jordão: I think I'd have to know more Scala to understand that properly - but yes, using composition rather than inheritance helps here too.

Comment: @Jon: take a look at it... It will give you a lot of fodder to your "wacky ideas" :-)

Comment: @Jordão: I tried to read it now, but didn't get terribly far. Maybe tomorrow, *not* at the end of a working day. I find it quite hard to read articles about one aspect of a programming language I'm not familiar with, when the article (understandably) assumes a reasonable degree of knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it would make sense to let the compiler compile such code.

On the other side I understand the situation in which you are. The fix should be made on the code generator: it should not generate calls to abstract methods (can be checked using reflection). If you do not have access to the code of the code generator I am afraid you do not have many options...

You could create a facade object that is derived from A but implements all abstract methods as empty virtual ones and manipulate the code generator to use it instead of A.

Comment: I'm glad you understand my point! I'm not really looking for a solution to a problem I have. I used the code generation thing as an example of something that exists so people can relate.

Answer (score 1):

I see what you mean. Sometimes it might be convenient to just don't care whether a base class method is abstract or not. But, a subclass is already [very coupled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragile_base_class) to its parent class, so much that the compiler knows exactly what calls are valid and issues error messages accordingly. There're no *virtual* base classes.

What you can do is define an *adapter* class. Kind of a no-op that will just implement the abstract methods to do nothing. It might not be feasible if they return values and you can't decide what *default* value to return. You would now derive from the adapter and call its non-abstract methods.

**UPDATE**

You *can* solve your "requirement" by using reflection. Instead of this:

```
base.StartProcess();
```

You'd use something like this:

```
this.BaseCall("StartProcess");
```

This would call `StartProcess` on your base class *only* if it's not abstract.

Here's the ugly code to make it work (which also considers parameters and default return values):

```
public static class BaseExtensions {
  public static void BaseCall(this object self, string methodName, params object[] parameters) {
    self.BaseCall(methodName, typeof(void), null, parameters);
  }
  public static T BaseCallWithReturn<T>(this object self, string methodName, T defaultReturn = default(T), params object[] parameters) {
    return (T)self.BaseCall(methodName, typeof(T), defaultReturn, parameters);
  }
  private static object BaseCall(this object self, string methodName, Type returnType, object defaultReturn, object[] parameters) {
    var parameterTypes = parameters.Select(p => p.GetType()).ToArray();
    if (self.GetType().BaseType == null) return null;
    var method = self.GetType().BaseType.GetMethod(methodName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, parameterTypes, null);
    if (method == null || method.IsAbstract) return defaultReturn;
    var dm = new DynamicMethod(methodName, returnType, new Type[] { self.GetType() }.Concat(parameterTypes).ToArray(), self.GetType());
    var il = dm.GetILGenerator();
    PushParameters(il, parameterTypes.Length);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, method);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
    return dm.Invoke(null, new object[] { self }.Concat(parameters).ToArray());
  }
  private static void PushParameters(ILGenerator il, int n) {
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      switch (i+1) {
        case 1: il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1); break;
        case 2: il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_2); break;
        case 3: il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_3); break;
        default: il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_S, i+1); break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is it worth it? I'll let *you* decide.

Comment: @Jordão, +1. I think you get my point. However, if the base class is changed in the future to include an implementation (keeping the method virtual obviously) then descendants will not be calling that implementation because they could do so earlier.

Comment: @Jackie: If an implementation is added later, then it doesn't make sense for the method to be abstract, does it? It should be declared virtual with a no-op implementation to start with, in which case it's fine for the derived classes to call `base.Foo`. Just because you're not in control of the abstract class or the code generator in your specific example doesn't mean the language designers made the wrong choice.

Comment: @Jackie Kirby: when you change a base class, there's no guarantee that the subclasses will behave as expected. So you always have to _recompile_ and _retest_ the sub classes anyway. Now _that's_ how coupled they are.

Comment: Composition, not inheritance, would really solve your problem. If you compose a class, you can safely call its abstract methods, and they'll be resolved at runtime with virtual method dispatching.

Comment: @Jon, are you saying that every class you've ever designed you've never changed the design? "language designers made the wrong choice", I didn't say or imply they did, is that what you get from my question? If the language ignores some things (when it suits) then I'm wondering if this could be one of those cases well. You don't have to see a run time error, but you probably should see a compile time warning.

Comment: @Jordão, Yes, there is no guarantee ever is there? One could say the same thing about a descendant calling base.Foo() and the implementation of Foo() changes. No one seems to have a problem with that. The re-compile and re-test goes for anything/everything. It's not specific to what I'm suggesting. What I'm suggesting is not going to break anything that's already out there and it implies re-test and re-compile just like everything else does.

Comment: @Jackie: you're right, this kind of dependency problem is not just limited to your example. But you can have a greater separation with interfaces, for example, that you can't have with inheritance. Depending on the coupling of the dependencies, you might just need to retest, without the recompile phase. With the special nature of inheritance, you always need to recompile as well.

Comment: @Jackie: You said: "Could not the complier/Jitter simply ignore such a call and issue a warning instead of error?" I inferred from that that you believe the language would have been better if that were the case, in other words that the language designers made the wrong choice. Are you *not* suggesting that the language should work differently? If so, I'm confused as to what you *are* suggesting...

Comment: @Jon, yes the language designers made *a* choice. In a "discussion" of this nature I would expect intelligent dialog about the pros and cons rather than close minded point of view or making statements such as "designers made the right or wrong choice". They (the language designers) and not infallible (and they know it too) I could rattle of many bad/wrong deign choices they've made, but I do know that one designs around the known universe of knowledge/requirements and there are always constraints one has to consider. But I'm looking for a discussion or a debate.

Comment: @Jackie: I never said they *are* infallible, and there are plenty of places where I disagree with them too. I'm saying that *in this case* I believe they've made the right decision, I've said why, and I've said what I believe the appropriate alternatives are in situations such as the one you've described.

Answer (score 0):

You are deriving `ClassC` from `ClassA`, what would you expect base.StartProcess to actually do?

Do you really mean to derive from `ClassB`